# Initial value of dropdown mat-select using formControlName not reflected in UI

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a dropdown mat-select that is created dynamically via Form Builder and displayed in a series of loops and supplied an initial value, but the dropdown itself is not actually set.

```
const control = this.formBuilder.control(value, validators);
myForm.addControl(id, control);
debugger;
```

The html to display is

```
<mat-select [value]="getFormValue(input.id)" [formControlName]="input.name" [placeholder]="idForDebug">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of input.dropdownOptions" [value]="option.fieldValue">
        {{option.display}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I also tried the above with/without the [value] param supplied, since I'm already using [formControlerName]. Same behavior each way

getFormValue is defined as

```
public getFormValue(id) {
    debugger;
    return myForm.get(id).value;
}
```

I have confirmed via debugger that the value and id match both when I create the control and in the getFormValue method. If all the data is there and supplied, why is the dropdown value not set? What would I be missing?

Confirmed via console and debugger all values and IDs match in all 3 locations above, yet dropdown is not pre-selected.

-- I created a simplified version of this on stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pggkbk

In this live example I would expect the dropdown to be pre-populated with the value `1` since that's what is supplied when the control is created via

```
const control = this.formBuilder.control(1, []);
```

**solved**

I feel silly, the values coming in from the db were as Strings, so when I set the dropdown value to the string but compared it to the [value] from dropdownOptions which was a numbers, they never matched.

ParseInt(value) and everything worked out gravy

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example so we can debug it?

Comment: `myForm.get(` takes formCntrolName as an argument and as it seems, it is not `input.id`- , but - `[formControlName]="input.name"`, so try to pass the correct name - `[value]="getFormValue(input.name)"`

Comment: just when create the control: `this.formBuilder.control(input.dropdownOptions[0].fieldValue, validators);`, BUT you need **remove** the [value] from mat-select tag, (you has already [formControlName])

Comment: @Eliseo thanks for the suggestion I tried that, same behavior. Which is weird the value from formBuilder.control and displayed in the UI to confirm IDs are equal, match perfectly. Yet the dropdown is not pre-filled. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius That's just how I left it for the example. The IDs match I confirmed via debugger we are comparing the matching values everywhere.

Comment: @JoshuaOhana, I add an answer

Comment: @EneaJahollari I added stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pggkbk

Comment: @Eliseo I added a stackblitz with an example of the issue I'm seeing and more explanation https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pggkbk

Answer (score 1):

Really I don't understand your question. I imagine you has an array of inputs like

```
inputs=[{
    name:'select',
    dropdownOptions:[
    {fieldValue: 'steak-0', display: 'Steak'},
    {fieldValue: 'pizza-1', display: 'Pizza'},
    {fieldValue: 'tacos-2', display: 'Tacos'}

    ]
  }]
```

And a variable "data" with the values

```
  data:any={select:'pizza-1'}
```

If you use a variable form in a NgOnInit you can use some like

```
  form=new FormGroup({})
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.inputs.forEach(x=>{
      this.form.addControl(x.name,new FormControl(this.data[x.name]))
    })
  }
```

well, you can give value to the formControl with the first value of option

```
  this.form.addControl(x.name,new FormControl(x.dropdownOptions[0].fieldValue))
```

Then you display the form like

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngFor="let input of inputs">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
            <mat-select  [formControlName]="input.name" [placeholder]="idForDebug">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of input.dropdownOptions" [value]="option.fieldValue">
                    {{option.display}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</form>
```

take a look to the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqkqdk-wzv3np?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-form-example.ts). remember, to give value a FormControl not use [value], just change the value of control. You can make when you create the form, or using [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setvalue)